# nuget pack ignores package.config dependencies

Tags: nuget, dependency-management, nuget-package

I cannot get `nuget pack X.csproj` to recognize package dependencies in a project. Amazingly, when packaging, the diagnostic message *“Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies”* is printed, but in the end the `<dependencies/>` tag in the `.nuspec` file inside the package is empty.

The `packages.config` for the project does indeed contain references:

```
<packages>
  <package id="SmartAction.Logger" version="1.0.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="SmartAction.Pervasive" version="1.0.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

To narrow the problem down, I removed my own parallel `.nuspec` file, and mostly all switches from the `nuget pack` command:

```
> nuget pack libToneDetection.csproj -prop Configuration=Release

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Attempting to build package from 'libToneDetection.csproj'.
Packing files from '[snip]\Core\ToneDetection\libToneDetection\bin\Release'.
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
Successfully created package '[snip]\Core\ToneDetection\libToneDetection\SmartAction.Audio.ToneDetection.1.0.0.0.nupkg'.
```

NuGet Version: 3.3.0.212

The only difference I can spot with this project is that its name is different from package name (I am trying to maintain them in sync but this is older stuff I am repackaging).

I doubt I had ever seen this before. I am finding questions on SO from people trying to *prevent* references in packages.config from becoming dependencies of the package, but none from those trying, like me, to beat the reverse problem. Help!

---

**Addendum.** I copied the project out of the solution with other projects to a temporary directory and rebuilt the package from there. Now *one of the two* dependencies from `packages.config` was added to the package:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="SmartAction.Logger" version="1.0.2.0" />
</dependencies>
```

Thinking of the differences between the two, the `SmartAction.Logger` package depends on `SmartAction.Pervasive`. But the package I am compiling really uses both.

To me, either behavior looks incorrect. Am I hitting a nuget bug, or a cryptic complex feature?

Xref: Opened https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1867

Comment: @Rao: our edits crossed. I added your suggested tags by hand, sorry!

Comment: Having a similar issue -- did you solve this?

Comment: @JoshuaEvensen, read https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1867. In short, it is not possible after the fact to distinguish packages added to package.config by the user from those added as dependencies, so that NuGet tries to guess. In the case like this, it guesses wrong.